# Restrict a specific character on jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How do I not allow the `JTextField` to have the number 0 only to be typed? I am currently working on a simple sales system and I was trying to make an error message when the number 0 is inputted to the quantity text field yet the purchase will still be recorded with the quantity of 0.

Comment: *How do I not allow the JTextField to have the number 0 only to be typed?* - well you need to allow the user to type "0" because they many want to enter "10". So this problem is solved by doing an edit check BEFORE you start your processing.  What about if the user types an "a, b, c..." etc? Don't use a JTextField. Instead you can use a `JSpinner`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

Comment: Is there a way where the number 0 would not be allowed to be typed if it is the initial number? I was thinking of a JTextField that would consume if the first digit is zero but would allow zero in the next digits.

Comment: And what it the user types "10" and then deletes the "1"? You still haven't answered my question about the user entering "a" or "b" or "c". Why do you only care about the 0? If you use a text field you have to edit for all possible characters that can be typed. You can always use a `DocumentFilter` as I mentioned below but I proposed a simpler solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener 
{
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
    assistText();
    }
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
    assistText();
    }
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
    //Plain text components do not fire these events
    }           
private void assistText() {
    Runnable doAssist = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //here recognizes if exist a 0 and do your task
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doAssist);
}
```

Comment: (1-) you would NOT use a DocumentListener. The Document has already been updated with the value. If you really want to restrict the typing of "0" you would use a DocumentFilter. But this does not makes sense either. See my comment to the question.